# Asus ZenBook UX501VW HDD Low Speed

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, asus

I've got an Asus ZenBook UX501VW with 1TB hard drive as `smartctl -i /dev/sdb` introduces it:

```
    smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-59-generic] (local build)
    Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

    === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
    Device Model:     ST1000LM035-1RK172
    Serial Number:    WCB0HALD
    LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 09be76a03
    Firmware Version: SDM1
    User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
    Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
    Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
    Form Factor:      2.5 inches
    Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
    ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
    SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
    Local Time is:    Tue Jan 31 05:11:02 2017
    SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
    SMART support is: Enabled
```

But the problem is that R/W processes are very slow and time-consuming even when I wanna open the drive, it opens with some significant latency.

The output of `sudo iotop -P` is as follows (after sort):

[image]

I'm using **Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS** and I've formatted it as NTFS drive.

I want to know whether the disk has flaws or ubuntu 16.04 has got some incompatibility with it.

Comment: Any idea to deal with this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some links that may help you:

1- To get real speed of R/W: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-benchmark.html

2- To tune HD: http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Tune-Your-Hard-Disk-with-hdparm

3- And to speed up ubuntu (If problem is in OS): https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-ubuntu-1310/

Thanks